# How to connect Power BI to Apache Spark on local machine?

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am newbie in Power BI.What are the configurations need to connect Power BI to spark on my local machine? I found some documents that mentioned spark over Azure's HDInsight .But didn't find any reference materials for connecting Spark to remote machine?
Is it possible?

Comment: following is the previously mentioned link that refers steps for connecting spark over Azure's HDInsight
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-spark-on-hdinsight-with-direct-connect/